# Rails & Slim: autoclosed tag does not fetch content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have this template:

```
div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-16"
  - if @campaign.errors.any?
    ul
  - @campaign.errors.full_messages.each do |e|
    li |e
= form_for @campaign do |f|
  div.form-group
  = f.label :name, class: "control-label"
  = f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"
  div.form-group
  = f.label :ad_link, class: "control-label"
  = f.text_field :link, class: "form-control"
  div.form-group
  = f.label :image, class: "control-label"
  = f.file_field :campaign_image, class: "file"
  div.form-group
  = f.submit "Create campaign"
```

Which renders following html:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-16"></div>
<form ...> </form>
```

So it gets me to empty div and form under, instead of form inside of div.

I tried to solve it by inserting usual html:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-16">
      - if @campaign.errors.any?
        ul
      - @campaign.errors.full_messages.each do |e|
        li |e
    = form_for @campaign do |f|
      div.form-group
      = f.label :name, class: "control-label"
      = f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"
      div.form-group
      = f.label :ad_link, class: "control-label"
      = f.text_field :link, class: "form-control"
      div.form-group
      = f.label :image, class: "control-label"
      = f.file_field :campaign_image, class: "file"
      div.form-group
      = f.submit "Create campaign"
</div>
```

But it turned out in some strange output, where form tag started inline inside div and didn't capture any fields or submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is very important in `slim`. Look [there](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames) the docs. So, you must write smth like this:

```
div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-16"
  |
  - if @campaign.errors.any?
    ul
  - @campaign.errors.full_messages.each do |e|
    li |e
  = form_for @campaign do |f|
      div.form-group
        = f.label :name, class: "control-label"
        = f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"
      div.form-group
        = f.label :ad_link, class: "control-label"
        = f.text_field :link, class: "form-control"
      div.form-group
        = f.label :image, class: "control-label"
        = f.file_field :campaign_image, class: "file"
      div.form-group
        = f.submit "Create campaign"
```